# Getting a "Cannot add or udate a child row: a foreign key constraint fails"

Tags: sql, mariadb, foreign-keys

Okay so here is the tables I'm referencing with an `INSERT` statement:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Order_Item
(
    autogen      INT auto_increment,
    order_num_FK VARCHAR(20),
    item_num_FK  CHAR(20),

    CONSTRAINT order_item_PK PRIMARY KEY (autogen),

    CONSTRAINT order_item_FK1 FOREIGN KEY (order_num_FK)
    REFERENCES Pizza_Order(order_num),

    CONSTRAINT order_item_FK2 FOREIGN KEY (item_num_FK)
    REFERENCES Pizza(item_num)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Pizza_Toppings 
(
    autogen_FK  INT auto_increment,
    item_num_FK CHAR(20),

    CONSTRAINT Pizza_Toppings_FK1 FOREIGN KEY (autogen_FK)
    REFERENCES Order_Item(autogen),

    CONSTRAINT Pizza_Toppings_FK2 FOREIGN KEY (item_num_FK)
    REFERENCES Toppings(item_num)
);
```

Here is the `INSERT` statement:

```
INSERT INTO Pizza_Toppings(autogen_FK, item_num_FK)
VALUES (1, "I10"), (1, "I12"), (2, "I14"), 
       (3, "I11"), (3, "I12"), (3, "I13"),
       (4, "I12"), (4, "I13"), (5, "I14"),
       (6, "I14"), (7, "I10"), (9, "I10"),
       (10, "I10"), (10, "I11"), (10, "I12"), 
       (10, "I13"), (10, "I14"), (11, "I15");
```

error message:

> Cannot add or update a child row:a foriegnkey constrain fails ("pizzadelivery_db.pizza_toppings_FK1" FOREIGN KEY ("autogen_FK) Refrences "order_item(autogen))

I would greatly appreciate some help... Thank you

Comment: Your insert statement has nothing to do with declared tables. Please, clarify the question

Comment: Please show the creation of Pizza_Toppings here. The error means that whatever you are referring to with item_num_FK does not exist in the table it refers to.

Comment: oh sorry thank you ill include now

Answer (score 0):

1. On table Pizza_Toppings, column autogen_FK is auto_increment and you are passing values to it . seems like you have to **remove "auto_increament"** because since its a fk it doesn't make sense to be auto increment and it solves your issue.
2. Also the values you are inserting to autogen_FK , should exists in Order_Item (autogen)

you insert statement is correct , only values are not valid

see db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.5&fiddle=7861519fc2e1e3998e639432994ddf11)

Comment: hey, ty. I dropped the auto_increament and am still getting the same issue

Comment: @zAKyYyBoyYyYyYayYyY1000 also for reference which dbms are you using? add the complete error message to your question

Comment: ty, I am using maria Db...here is the message 'Cannot add or update a child row:a foriegnkey constrain fails ("pizzadelivery_db.pizza_toppings_FK1" FOREIGN KEY ("autogen_FK) Refrences "order_item(autogen))

Comment: then it is the second point issue , you are inserting a value into intp autogen_FK that is violating FK meaning it doesn't exists in its referenced table

Comment: Damn im so confused im only entering random numbers into both order_item(autogen) and pizza_topping(autogen_FK) idk what im doing wrong

Comment: can you help me more i really am still stuck on this

Comment: that's the problem you can't insert random numbers, see fiddle link in my asnwer